# Only enabled Administrator accounts

Tags: powershell

I use The below script to get remote administrator account names, I get all the administrator enabled / disabled. I wanted to just get enabled administrator accounts / get the status of the account whether it is enabled / disabeld. Have tried but failed. Can anyone please help.

```
    $Computers = Get-Content "D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\servers.txt"
    foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $strcomputer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $Computer + ",computer")
    $Group = $strcomputer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
    $members= $Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',      $null, $_, $null)}
    $Computer | Add-Content D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\export.xls
        ForEach($user in $members){
        $user | Add-Content D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\export.xls
    }
    Write-Host ""
   }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I dont get any error , i get all accounts enabled / disabled . I am unable to filter only ENABLED local user accounts.Or If i cud get details whether account is enabled/disabled .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the end of your script by retrieving each user object member of the Administrators group and verify that it is not Disabled in the userFlags property of the object.

```
$Computers = Get-Content "D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\servers.txt"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $strcomputer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $Computer + ",computer")
    $Group = $strcomputer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
    $members= $Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',      $null, $_, $null)}

    $Computer | Add-Content D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\export.xls
    ForEach($user in $members)
    {
        $userObj = [ADSI]("WinNT://" +$computer+"/"+ $user)

        if ($userObj.UserFlags -ne $null)
        {
            $flags = $userObj.UserFlags[0]

            if ($flags -band 512) # 512 = enabled, 2 = disabled
            {
                $user | Add-Content D:\doc\Work\sCRIPTS\export.xls  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error - "Cannot index into a null array"

Comment: Let me add the rest of the code(i.e. the beginning), so we are sure we have it in its entirety

Comment: Thanx for the help but I am still getting the same error- "Cannot index into null array". It showing error for the foll line: $flags = $userObj.UserFlags[ <<<< 0]

Comment: Is it maybe a group inside that group? it would not have those flags, let me fix the code.